# Json response value is not setting to the Bean class

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, resttemplate

When I do rest class I have received below response.

Response:

```
     {
            "_index": "a_index",
"total":9,
            "_type": "e",
            "_id": "BSKnamtd_8-egMNvh",
            "_data": 2.076404564,
            "_secure": {
              "email": "abcd1@gmail.com"
            }
          }
```

To set this response. I have created pojo class as shown blow.

```
public class data implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 644188100766481108L;
    private String _index;
    private Integer total;
    private String _type;
    private String _id;
    private Double _data;
    private Source _secure;

    public String getIndex() {
        return _index;
    }

    public void setIndex(String _index) {
        this._index = _index;
    }

    public Integer getTotal() {
        return total;
    }

    public void setTotal(Integer total) {
        this.total = total;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return _type;
    }

    public void setType(String _type) {
        this._type = _type;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return _id;
    }

    public void setId(String _id) {
        this._id = _id;
    }

    public Double getData() {
        return _data;
    }

    public void setData(Double _data) {
        this._data = _data;
    }

    public Source getSecure() {
        return _secure;
    }

    public void setSecure(Source _secure) {
        this._secure = _secure;

    }

}
```

When I hit the restClient call, I am getting only "total" value remaining values getting as null. "total" variable not having underscore("*") remaining variables have "*" so that I am facing Issue..?

Please help how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The Json object is

```
...
"_index": "a_index",
"total":9,
...
```

And the properties for those two properties are:

```
 public void setIndex(String _index) {
        this._index = _index;
    }

public void setTotal(Integer total) {
        this.total = total;
    }
```

As you can see, the **java property** for the **Json _index property** is **index (setIndex)**.

**index** is different from **_index**, so when the Json object is mapped it gets null, because it can't find the property _index.

In the other hand you have that the **java property** for the **Json total property** is **total (setTotal)**.

In this case the properties in Json and Java have the same name, so it gets the value loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Java class property name is invisible to object mapper (it is `private`).  What matters in your case is getter/setter name.  It is used to map JSON object property name to Java class (POJO).

You have two options I can think of. Dirty one is just to change setter names to `set_index ()`, `set_type()`, etc so that they correspond to JSON property names, or you can do it right:

1. Change  names of Java class properties and methods to standard convention so that code is nice and  readabl.
2. Annotate properties with `@JsonProperty` to express different that default mapping between JSON  and Java object.

From Annotation Type JsonProperty Java docs:

> Default value ("") indicates that the field name is used as the
>   property name without any modifications, but it can be specified to
>   non-empty value to specify different name. Property name refers to
>   name used externally, as the field name in JSON objects.

Example with annotation:

```
public class test {

    @JsonProperty("_index")
    private String index;

    private Integer total;

    @JsonProperty("_type")
    private String type;

    public String getIndex() { return index; }
    public void setIndex(String index){ this.index = index; }

    public Integer getTotal() { ... }
    public void setTotal(Integer total) { ... }

    public String getType() { ... }
    public void setType(String type) { ... }
    ....
}
```